# How to accomplish initial Splitter and SplitItem layout with enaml?

Tags: python, enaml

I'm using the [enaml](http://docs.enthought.com/enaml/index.html) toolkit and would like to know how to initialize `Splitter` / `SplitItem` layouts.

Below is some very simple sample code. I'd like the window to start with the left `SplitItem` taking about 2/3 of the window width with the right `SplitItem` getting the other third. I've tried a variety of constraints in a variety of places but can't seem to hit on what I need to  do.

Window starts like this:
[image: equal width split items]

I want it to start like this: 
[image: left split item wider]

```
from enaml.widgets.api import (
    Window, Container, Splitter, SplitItem, Html
    )

enamldef Left(Container):
    Html:
        source = '<center><h1>Hello Left!</h1></center>'

enamldef Right(Container):
    Html:
        source = '<center><h1>Hello Right!</h1></center>'

enamldef Main(Window):
    initial_size = (800,400)
    Container:

        Splitter:

            SplitItem:
                Left:lt:
                    pass

            SplitItem:
                Right:rt:
                    pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `stretch` attribute on each `SplitItem`. The initial widths will be proportional to the fraction of total stretch values. So for the left one, use `stretch = 3` and the right one `stretch = 1`. This will allocate 3/4 of the space to the left side and 1/4 of the space to the right side. The stretch values must be integers, not floating point values since this is what the underlying toolkits are expecting.

Comment: That was it. Thanks, Robert! Also, I'd like to suggest that someone with more reputation than me create a new `enaml` tag. It sure would've been nice to see that property in the [docs](http://docs.enthought.com/enaml/api_ref/widgets/enaml.widgets.split_item.SplitItem.html#enaml.widgets.split_item.SplitItem).

Comment: @JefferyRPrice: I added the enaml tag.